# What does $\partial_ν/\partial^2$ mean?

Tags: definition, differentiation, notation

I found such notation in this article [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07477), equations 24-25. I know that $\partial_μ$ is four-gradient, but it does not contain second-order derivatives. Only d'Alembert operator does, $\partial^μ\partial_μ$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fundamentally notation with the following meaning: $1/\partial^2$ is the inverse operator of $\partial^2$. And what does this imply? Basically, that under Fourier transform if $\partial^2$ goes to $p^2$, then $1/\partial^2$ will go to $1/p^2$. In effective field theory, with this reasoning, you can expand in powers of $m^2/\partial^2$ and if momenta is larger than mass then you drop such terms.

Comment: What is $\partial^2$? Is it differentiation in transverse direction, assuming $μ$=0..3?

Comment: @Peter, $\partial^2 \equiv \partial^\mu \partial_\mu$

Comment: What about massless particles?

Comment: @Peter I guess that for massless particles, expansion is not in powers of $m^2/\partial^2$ but $\Lambda^2/\partial^2$ for $\Lambda$ some scale of your theory for which it make sense $\Lambda^2/p^2 \ll 1$